# Mapping multiple derived entities to a single table in Doctrine 1.x

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, command-line-interface, entities, derived

I have a entity Item (that is mapped to a table application_item, lets say) and there are several entities that are derived from the Item. The derived entities contain additional getters/setters (without their respective fields) that simply get/set property of the parent class (in some text field, where the property is added as encoded json).

```
// part of Item.php 
class Item
{
  // other fields in the parent class

  public $properties;

  public getProperty($name)
  {
      // decode $properties and get $name from it
  }
  // getter, setters in the parent class
}

// part of DerivedEntity1.php
class DerivedEntity1 extends Item
{
   public getField1($field1)
   {
      return $this->getProperty($field1); 
   }

}
```

There should be only one table generated. I am trying to generate tables using doctrine 1.x but it says Item is not defined, even if I am adding Use \Item; as well.

Comment: I think, I found the solution for it myself given here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html